# Filling dictionary in while loop

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I am working in excel VBA. I have a list with articles and prices which I want to add into a dictionary.

[image: Picture of Articles]

I made a class with 3 objects, Artikelnaam, ArtikelNummer and prijs.
I want to store these into the dictionary with index starting at 1.

For some reason the macro will always use row 19 , column B C D
and fill the whole dictionary with those values.
Thus every KEY contains the values from the last row.

```
Public Function filldict() As Dictionary
On Error GoTo errorhandle

Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim k As Long
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
Set oTest = New Artikel
Dim Row As Integer
Row = 4
Dim Index As Integer
Index = 1

' Counts the rows of articles
k = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("A4", Worksheets("Blad1").Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

' Loops thru all rows of articles and adds them to dict
Do While i < k
    oTest.ArtikelNaam = Worksheets("Blad1").Cells(Row, 2).Value
    oTest.ArtikelNummer = Worksheets("Blad1").Cells(Row, 3).Value
    oTest.Prijs = Worksheets("Blad1").Cells(Row, 4).Value

    dict.Add Index, oTest
    
    i = i + 1
    Row = Row + 1
    Index = Index + 1
Loop
   
' Set
Set filldict = dict

Exit Function
errorhandle:
MsgBox Err.Description & ", Function filldict."
End Function
```

Comment: and, the value of `k` is ?  I think, whn you debug your code, you will find out that it's `19`?

Comment: I'd suspect you have previously used this worksheet and the range of rows is greater than 11. Put a breakpoint after 
*k = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("A3", Worksheets("Blad1").Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count*
and examine the value of k.
You can always copy the rows to a new sheet and try again.

Comment: To find why this would be easy by single-stepping through the code.

Comment: Or select row 12 to 19, and delete those rows Because the formula `=ISBLANK(A12)` will not return True, see: https://superuser.com/questions/837038/excel-how-to-create-truly-blank-cells-from-formula-so-that-they-wont-show-up

Comment: value of k = 15...

Comment: @Luuk I already tried to delete everything below row 12. Even till row 30. Didnt work

Comment: Column `A` looks pretty empty. Try using another one: `k = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("B4", Worksheets("Blad1").Range("B4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count`.

Comment: Deleting rows does not always affect row.count. Read more here: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

Comment: I cleared the rows below A12 again and now:
Using k = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("A4", Worksheets("Blad1").Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count gives me k =  1048576 

k = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("B4", Worksheets("Blad1").Range("B4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count gives me k = 8

Comment: Maybe you should also add a check if there  is a value in column B.

Comment: OMG column A is super empty.. 

I made a mistake wow... ofcourse I should use column B .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
k = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("A4", Worksheets("Blad1").Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

to

```
k = Worksheets("Blad1").Range("B4", Worksheets("Blad1").Range("B4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

And moving

```
Set oTest = New Artikel
```

Inside the Do While

Answer (score 1):

### Class to Dictionary

- Not tested.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function filldict() As Dictionary
    On Error GoTo errorhandle
    
    Const cCol As String = "B"
    Const fRow As Long = 4
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    With wb.Worksheets("Blad1")
        Dim lRow As Long: lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cCol).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim oTest As Artikel
        Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
        Dim cRow As Long
        For cRow = fRow To lRow
            Set oTest = New Artikel
            oTest.ArtikelNaam = .Cells(cRow, "B").Value
            oTest.ArtikelNummer = .Cells(cRow, "C").Value
            oTest.Prijs = .Cells(cRow, "D").Value
            dict.Add cRow - fRow + 1, oTest
        Next cRow
        Set filldict = dict
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
errorhandle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & ", Function filldict."
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

One way to simplify this task is to design Artikel To be a self generating factory Object.  You can then greatly simplify the code in the original post.

Class Artikel

```
Option Explicit
'@PredeclaredId
'@Exposed

Private Enum ArtikelIndex

    aiNaam = 1
    aiNummer
    aiPrijs
    
End Enum

Private Type Properties

    ' I'm using variant here but you should use the correct variable type here
    ' and in the property definitions
    
    Naam                 As Variant
    Nummer               As Variant
    Prijs                As Variant

End Type

Private p                       As Properties



' DO not use the Private Sub Class_Initialize()
' This function is taken over by the Make and Self functions


Public Property Get Make(ByVal ipItems As Variant) As Artikel

    With New Artikel
    
        Set Make = .Self(ipItems)
        
    End With
    
End Property

Public Property Get Self(ByVal ipItems As Variant) As Artikel

    p.Naam = ipItems(1, aiNaam)
    p.Nummer = ipItems(1, aiNummer)
    p.Prijs = ipItems(1, aiPrijs)
    
    Set Self = Me
    
End Property

Public Property Get Naam() As Variant
    Naam = p.Naam
End Property

Public Property Get Nummer() As Variant
    Nummer = p.Nummer
End Property

Public Property Get Prijs() As Variant
    Prijs = p.Prijs
End Property
```

You can then simplify the original code as follows

```
Option Explicit

Public Function filldict() As Dictionary

    Dim LastRowIndex As Long
    LastRowIndex = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad1").Range("B4").End(xlDown).Row
    
    Dim myRange As Excel.Range
    Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blad1").Range("B4", "D" & CStr(LastRowIndex))

    Dim myRow As Excel.Range
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For Each myRow In myRange.Rows
    
        dict.Add dict.Count + 1, Artikel.Make(myRow.Range("A1:C1").Value2)
        'Debug.Print dict.Item(dict.Count).Naam
        'Debug.Print dict.Item(dict.Count).Nummer
        'Debug.Print dict.Item(dict.Count).Prijs

    Next

    Set filldict = dict
    
End Function
```

It should be noted that the object instance is immutable because we supplied the values in the initial Make constructor but do not provide any Let Properties to reassign the values after the instance has been created.

The code above uses RubberDuck and Rubberduck annotations to simplify setting parameters that are not visible in the VBA IDE.  WIthout RubberDuck you have to export, set the atrribute values yourself, and then reimport. If you don't have RubberDuck installed (a fantastic and free add on for VBA) then you should do so immediately.

Comment: The ```Artikel``` class is not immutable. Internal state can be easily changed by calling the ```.Self``` property with new values on an existing instance. To truly achieve immutability, no public methods of the class should be allowed to change the internal state. However, you can achieve immutability with a combination of factory and private initializer method. See the ```RedirectInstance``` routine inside the [VBA-MemoryTools](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-MemoryTools) repo.

Comment: Then we just add a line to the self procedure that raises an error if it is called more than once.  Its enough of a bodge as it is so one extra line of bodging shouldn't be an issue. Then we have no need to go playing around with the innards of VBA as you do in your repo.

Comment: I agree. It works. Although, raising a runtime error is not the same as having code that doesn't allow the call entirely at compile time. Hence, it's not real immutability. Too bad the language doesn't have constructors. [twinBasic](https://www.twinbasic.com/) will have though